# Whitespace In AngularJS Jade templates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pug

I have the following problem:

```
p
  directive(attr="foo")
  | (
  directive(attr="bar")
  |)
```

Desired output is:

```
<directive attr="foo"></directive> (<directive attr="bar"></directive>)
```

But the way Jade is processed the whitespace is introduced after the first parentheses like:

```
<directive attr="foo"></directive> (  <directive attr="bar"></directive>)
```

Is there a way to ignore the whitespace after the first parentheses? Or should I find a workaround with Angular maybe?

Comment: directive(attr="foo") (

Comment: directive(attr="bar") )   Remove the bars

Comment: If I do that then the second directive fails to be parsed properly. i.e. It just puts the second directive's markup in parentheses and not the output of the directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
p
    | <directive attr="bar">(</directive><directive attr="bar">)</directive>
```